# BioPython Entrez not returning results when called as a module

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to use PubMed's Entrez to search papers via the BioPython module.  The issue that I'm having, is that when I run the search script as a standalone it works, but when I call it from another script it returns an empty result.  I've included the example below.

PaperSearch.py

```
from Bio import Entrez

def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'me@example.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                        sort='relevance',
                        retmax='50',
                        retmode='xml',
                        term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search('cancer')
    print(results)
```

Main.py

```
import PaperSearch

query = 'cancer'
results = PaperSearch.search(query)
print results
```

This is Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The module file name is PaperSearch.py, but it seems you did not import the correct name.

Change Main.py to:

```
import PaperSearch

query = 'cancer'
results = PaperSearch.search(query)
print results
```

Comment: Thanks azalea, it seems I'm good at making mistakes when copying and tidying up my code for stackoverflow.  Unfortunately this wasn't the issue

Comment: Then I have no idea. Your code runs as expected on my machine, and your answer does exactly the same thing as your original code, except that in your original code, you still use the wrong module name.

Comment: Yeah, it was really frustrating when I was debugging it, as I could run PaperSearch.py by itself and get the correct results, but it wouldn't return anything when I called it.  I'll try it in Linux when I get around to it and probably see it run just as it should.  Thanks for your help and time though.

Answer (score 0):

To get round this issue, I had to make a hack of calling the def from inside PaperSearch.py and then returning the output.

PaperSearch.py

```
from Bio import Entrez

def search(query):
    Entrez.email = 'me@example.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                    sort='relevance',
                    retmax='50',
                    retmode='xml',
                    term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results

def start_search(query):
    papers = search(query)

    return papers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = search('cancer')
    print(results)
```

Main.py

```
import PaperSearch

query = 'cancer'
results = PaperSearch.start_search(query)
print results
```

Not sure if this is because I'm running on Windows, but haven;'t tested out no Linux yet, as I'm writing this to be run on Windows only currently.